# Uri.builder vs string based url construction

Tags: android, url, uri

Why would one use Uri.Builder when Urls can be constructed by simply concatenating string variables?

In which cases is advisable to use uribuilder over string variables and vice-versa?

Answer (score 1):

Uri.Builder is a helper class using which you can offload the work of constructing various kinds of uri. It is always recommended to use this class instead of creating it yourself.

[Uri.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.Builder.html#build())

Comment: Yea but why is it recommended?

Comment: These classes are built very efficiently and they are less error prone that's why they are recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Only to make simple and easy to build URIs safely.

Answer (score 0):

Always prefer uribuilder over strings to build a uri as uribuilder has a lot of built-in validation to ensure that the given address is well-formed. Generally speaking, if you know that your uri is going to remain constant through out then you can go ahead and use a string but in the case when you will be often re-constructing your uri by changing/replacing fields, uribuilder is a must!